# Delete a table row if its unchecked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using a table each row contains a check box while i submit i want unchecked row to be disabled this is how i tried i created a table and row which contain a input type checked if the input type unchecked means i want to disable that row so while i retrieve in mvc i can get the details

```
<table id="subjectTable">
<tbody><tr><input type='checkbox' name='subjectcheck' /></tr></tbody>             
</table>
 $("input:not(:checked)").each(function () {
                        $(this).closest('tr').attr("disabled", "true");
                    });
```

this how i tried can any one help

Comment: What do you mean by `disable a <tr>` ? There's no such thing.

Comment: then i want to row the row which is not checked

Comment: You want to ... what ?

Comment: i want to remove the row if the check box is not selected while submitting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to simply remove the `<tr>`, you can use the jQuery methods [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) :

- Select your inputs with `$('input:not(:checked)')`
- Find the closest `<tr>` with `.closest('tr')`
- Remove them with `.remove()`

---

*PS: Keep in mind you have to have a `<td>` inside your `<tr>`, otherwise your `<input>` will be placed outside of your `<table>`.*

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('input:not(:checked)').closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="subjectTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='subjectcheck' /></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Emulate submit !</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the parent tr of unchecked `tr` try [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) like the following way:

```js
$("input:not(:checked)").each(function () {
  $(this).parent('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="subjectTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <input type='checkbox' name='subjectcheck'/>
    </tr>
  </tbody>             
</table>
```

Comment: not working i want to remove or disable the entire row if its unchecked